# Lumia 535 won't reset or start

Tags: reset, lumia-535

When I reset my phone, it only shows an icon with a gear and lightning bolt. See [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljIoO.jpg).

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried plugging in to a charger?

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded the Windows Device Recovery Tool? You can download it from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12379/windows-10-mobile-device-recovery-tool-faq

You will lose your files and apps if you use it, but the "Do I need to do anything before I use the tool?" section has some things to try before running the tool that might help you avoid losing your files and apps.